# Is my fork disc compatible?

Tags: brakes

Hello I'd like to show you my fork, is it compatible with shimano m355 non series hydraulic brakes?[image]

[image]

Comment: Take it to a bike shop & ask them if it is compatible if you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your fork is disc compatible, but your hub is not. The fork appears to have mounting points for the older 51mm I.S. disk brake standard. See

https://www.bikeman.com/bicycle-repair-tech-info/bikeman-tech-info/1638-51mm-international-standard-74mm-post-mount

for examples of the two most common styles of disk brake mounts.

Comment: im changing rims and hubs

Comment: if i change my hubs? do i need to change my cassette too?

Comment: No, just swap the old one to new wheel.

Comment: @Alexander could describe what you see that tells you that the fork is disk-compatible?

Comment: Also, what makes the rim not disk-compatible? I understand why a hub would not be disk-compatible, but I'm not so clear on what makes a rim disk-compatible or not.

Comment: The screw bosses in the OPs photo do appear to match those shown here: http://www.sheldonbrown.com/disc-brakes.html
& you are correct, dlu, the OP does not need to swap the rim out if building in a new hub.

Comment: @dlu thanks for the point. my mistake about "rim", I really mean hub. Thanks for the great editing, +1 for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, it is hard for me to judge scale in this photo, but those look more like fender/rack eyelets. One check would be to see if there were matching attachment points on the other side of the fork. If there are that would be a good sign that these are not mounting points for disk brakes. A clearer photo and a something for scale would help too.

Comment: what do you mean?  sorry im not so familiar with mtb parts

Comment: i just added another clearer photo, pls help i need advise